# wxListCtrl GetColumn() error?

Tags: wxwidgets, listctrl

I have a listctrl in my program, which has two columns that are populated with lots of elements. When the user clicks on one of them with a right click, I would like to know in which of the two columns the element lives.

My problem - the GetColumn() function returns either -1 (aka not found) or a zero -> even due I clicked in the second column (which should be 1 - they start from 0).

I had a look at the sample/listctrl but even there, GetColumn() always returns a 1 even if i click in another column.

I use wxWidgets 2.9.5 on Windows 7.

Here the code that i thought should work but doesn't:

```
Connect(ID_LISTBOX,wxEVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK,wxListEventHandler(X::OnRightClick));

....
void X::OnRightClick(wxListEvent& event)
{
    int a = event.GetColumn(); // returns - 1 aka not found
    int b = wxListItem(event.GetItem()).GetColumn();    // returns zero regardless     of the column

event.Skip();
}
```

How do I find out which column my element is in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`GetColumn()` only works for `EVT_LIST_COL_XXX` events, i.e. clicking on the column itself, as explicitly mentioned in the documentation. For the item clicks you need to explicitly call [HitTest()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ac346d7aa18722fb54580d4c4ed5cf113) and examine its return value and `ptrSubItem` output parameter value.